# ReactJs/Semantic UI check checkbox in loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

I render some `checkbox` via `json` data with `map`:

```
Data.FacData.map((v, i) => (
  <div key={i} className="CheckBox">
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      name="Facilities"
      value={v.id}
      onChange={this.getFacilities}
      id={"Facilities-"+v.id}
      />
    <label htmlFor={"Facilities-" + v.id}>{v.name}</label>
  </div>
))
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n95vzc3L/2/)**

It work fine and you can select any chekcbox and get it as array on console log (I handle and save it to database somehow) , but now I want to get what user selected before, from database (api), I got this data (object)

```
facilities: "1,3"
```

This mean user select checkbox `1` and `3`, I want to make checkbox checked, what I tried is use `defaultChecked` property, but it select all checkbox not only 1,3, any solution?

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n95vzc3L/4/)**

Comment: as below answer change id to string https://jsfiddle.net/knLjfw6q/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update your code like this
or refer https://jsfiddle.net/L7y2m8zr/17/
you need to convert the value string to array using split

```
componentDidMount() {
  /*get data from api*/
  const data = "1,3"
  const newValues = data.split(",").map(n => parseInt(n))
  this.setState({
    facilitiesValue: newValues
  });
}
```

also you can set the defaultChecked or checked value based on whether the array includes the given id, instead of just passing the array or string( since this is code and not magic :) )

```
return (
    <div>
    {
        Data.FacData.map((v, i) => (
        <div key={i} className="CheckBox">
             <input
             type="checkbox"
             name="Facilities"
             value={v.id}
             onChange={this.getFacilities}
             id={"Facilities-"+v.id}
             checked = {this.state.facilitiesValue.includes(parseInt(v.id))} 
            />
             <label htmlFor={"Facilities-" + v.id}>{v.name}</label>
        </div>
        ))
     }
    </div>
)
```

also update the onchange handler, to update the state

```
getFacilities = (e) => {
  const checked = this.state.facilitiesValue;
  let index;

  if (e.target.checked) {
    checked.push(parseInt(e.target.value))
  } else {
    index = checked.indexOf(parseInt(e.target.value))
    checked.splice(index, 1)
  }
  console.log(checked)
  this.setState({
    facilitiesValue: [...checked]
  })
};
```

Comment: Only issue is not able to checked/unchecked any checkbox

Comment: Thanks for your great answer, and your help